# Does rcx always point to the PEB at the process entrypoint?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, assembly, x86-64

64-bit Windows seems to call into an exe's entrypoint with `rcx = r8 = &PEB` and `rdx = r9 = &entrypoint` as if the entrypoint were declared `entrypoint(PEB *peb, void *entry)`.

Are these details specified anywhere or are these undocumented and not to be relied on?

Comment: It's got to be documented somewhere, but note that questions asking for external documentation or resources are off topic on this site.  I'm still interested in an answer.

Comment: modern windows (vista + or win7) call exe entry point with single parameter - address of *PEB*. this is not related to 64bit only. this for any. and this is not documented

Comment: RIP off topic question but RbMm's comment above sounds like an answer.

Comment: however you can relied on it, say exist **static** *nt.lib* inside wdk, it implement some miminal nt crt. may be design for boot execute apps, which can use only ntdll api. this lib **use** fact that first parameter is PEB pointer. you can link with this lib and in this case - for your application not crash - microsoft must not change in future that exe entry point take pointer to *PEB*. but if say true this is not very useful - no problem take PEB pointer without this

Comment: @fuz: IMO this question is totally fine.  It's asking about a specific fact, not *just* for documentation.  Questions of the form "this happens in one case; why?" or "Is it true in general / portable" get answered all the time by *citing* documentation to back up the answer, e.g. the ISO C++ standard.  If it was a problem, the last sentence could be rephrased to "do all Windows versions do this, and is it safe to depend on?" without explicitly mentioning documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

begin from vista windows call exe entry point with one param - address of *PEB*
so signature of exe entry point must be next

```
ULONG __stdcall ep(PEB* );
```

because in x64 the first parameter is passed via *rcx* register - you view address of *PEB* here. values in another registers is random. but how i say - this is not related to 64-bit only. in all windows versions will be address of *PEB* in first parameter.

this is not documented, but i sure very reliable and will not changed in new windows versions.

in *wdk* exist *nt.lib*. this is static (not import) library - which implement tiny crt for applications which can use only *ntdll.dll* import (primary boot execute apps, like *autochk.exe*) this library implement entry point of exe (`NtProcessStartup[W]`) which than called your `[w]main` with usual parameters. and `NtProcessStartup[W]` current implementation use pointer to `PEB` from first (and single) agrument. assume we link with current *nt.lib* implementation. because this is static lib - code of `NtProcessStartup[W]` will be inside your exe and not changed already. if windows no more will pass address of *PEB* in first argument - all exe which link with current *nt.lib* will crash on startup. so i think this already not be changed

Comment: Note that for native process creation via [`RtlCreateUserProcess`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/893a3c9d030fd8b078cbd747eeefd3f6ce57e560/sdk/lib/rtl/process.c#L178) (link to ReactOS implementation that should comply with Server 2003), NT has always passed the PEB address to the start routine. It wasn't new in Vista. You can see how `RtlCreateUserThread` sets up the stack for x86 in [`RtlInitializeContext`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/893a3c9d030fd8b078cbd747eeefd3f6ce57e560/sdk/lib/rtl/i386/thread.c#L22).

Comment: Prior to Vista, WINAPI `CreateProcessW` creates the initial context via `BaseCreateStack`and [`BaseInitializeContext`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/effdb6f232aa4448179c2b0a0f70aaa20856357c/dll/win32/kernel32/client/utils.c#L508), which in x86 sets the context to pass the startup address and PEB address in registers `EAX` and `EBX` to [`BaseProcessStartThunk`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/effdb6f232aa4448179c2b0a0f70aaa20856357c/dll/win32/kernel32/client/i386/thread.S#L29).

Comment: However, the thunk only pushes `EAX` (the start address) when calling [`BaseProcessStartup`](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/93220e26d078b566ed67d56adad79e7e1e4c16f0/dll/win32/kernel32/client/proc.c#L448). The PEB address in `EBX` is ignored, and the actual image start address is called without an argument. To repeat, this is prior to Vista.