# Why does Windows use RCX, RDX for pointers in a fresh x64 process, different from EAX, EBX in a newly created 32-bit process?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, cpu-registers

When I create a Windows **x86** process in a suspended state (`CREATE_SUSPENDED`) its `CONTEXT` contains:

- Virtual Address of Entry Point in `Eax` register;
- Virtual Address of [Process Environment Block structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb) in `Ebx` register.

But when I do the same for **x86_64** process then `CONTEXT` contains:

- Virtual Address of Entry Point in `Rcx` register (why not `Rax`?)
- Virtual Address of PEB structure in `Rdx` register (why not `Rbx`?)

It seems logical to me to take `Rax` in **x64** in place of `Eax` in **x86** and `Rbx` in **x64** in place of `Ebx` in **x86** .

But instead of `Eax`→`Rax` and `Ebx`→`Rbx` we see `Eax`→`Rcx` and `Ebx`→`Rdx`.

Also, I see that 64-bit Cheat Engine is aware of this when opening the 32-bit process (notice the migration of the values `eax`↔`ecx` and `ebx`↔`edx`:

[image: 64-bit context view of 32-bit process] [image: 32-bit context view of 32-bit process (holding Ctrl when expanding)]

What was the reason to move from `*ax` register to `*cx` and from `*bx` to `*dx` in 64-bit processes?

Is it somehow connected to [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)?

Is it related to Windows only or do other OSes also have this kind of register repurposing?

Update:
Screenshots of just created x64 process in a suspended state:
[image: RCX is entrypoint]

[image: PEB contains image base]

Comment: I'd assume it's related to the Windows x64 calling convention passing the first 2 args in RCX, RDX.  Or that `sysret` returns to user space with RIP=RCX, if this is stopping before the very first instruction that would execute in user space.  The 32-bit calling conventions (other than fastcall/vectorcall/thiscall) don't pass any args in registers, so the choice is more arbitrary.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: The PE spec does not say anything about the state of any registers when a .exe is started!

Comment: This is all implementation detail and subject to change at any time. It should also be obvious that the behavior must change from architecture to architecture. I mean, ARM, PowerPC, AArch64, MIPS, and Alpha AXP don't even have an *ax register!

Comment: Note also that 64-bit Cheat Engine is not "aware of this". It just shows the values in the registers. It makes no attempt to "understand" or "be aware of" what they mean. It's like saying that a telescope is "aware of" Saturn's moons. The telescope doesn't know anything about Saturn's moons. It just lets you see things that are far away.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ok, maybe it is just a coincidence, that entry point address is shown in the `*cx` register when not holding Ctrl (64-bit context) and in the `*ax` register when holding Ctrl (32-bit context). Same situation for PEB address: `*dx` (64-bit) → `*bx` (32-bit). But fun fact is: exactly this observation helped me to find the right registers when I was porting code from x86 to x64 ;)

Answer (score 2):

> It seems logical to me to take Rax in x64 in place of Eax in x86 and Rbx in x64 in place of Ebx in x86.

I don't see why it would be logical to assume so.
Even if, at MS, they had defined an internal ABI documenting the context of a just-created 32-bit process, the 64-bit version of would have been designed anew, so there is no reason to assume it carries anything over from the old 32-bit ABI.

If Windows uses `sysret` to return to user space, a process created with a suspended state may leak the target address in `rcx`.
Returning via other mechanisms (e.g. `iret/retf`), as could be the case for 32-bit code, will of course leak different data in different registers.

What you are seeing is probably an artifact of how Windows returns to user mode. I don't know exactly what the Windows kernel code to return to user mode is, but it is reasonable to assume that MS kept the same interface for 32-bit processes and that this interface was designed before `sysret` was widely used.

Note that at the **PE entry-point** `rcx` contains a pointer to the PEB and `rdx` to the entry-point (not the other way around). The former appears to be [an undocumented parameter passed to the entry-point function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684051/does-rcx-always-point-to-the-peb-at-the-process-entrypoint), the latter may be just an artifact of how the entry-point is called.
In fact, a 32-bit process will find a pointer to the PEB in the stack, as the first parameter for the PE entry-point code.

Regarding other OSes, anything that is not documented to be stable is free to change at any time (including what's left in the registers). This is true in general.
As far as stability goes, passing from a 32-bit to a 64-bit implementation is a pretty big step and, again, there is no reason to keep using a very old interface (but with wider registers) instead of improving it with all the recent knowledge.
You can easily see that, for example, Linux "repurposed" the registers in the 64-bit system call ABI.

Comment: The question's screenshots show one with EBX=something, EDX=0, the other with the reverse.  I have no idea what they mean by "(64 vs. 32)-bit context view of 32-bit process", but both screenshots only show 8x 32-bit registers so are clearly a 32-bit guest.  Possibly under a 32-bit vs. 64-bit kernel?  The "64-bit view" is the one that uses EDX; you could imagine that being the same kernel stuff invoking different user-space modes.  (Or even entering user-space in 64-bit mode and leaving it up to it to far-call to 32-bit mode, opposite how system calls have to far call -> syscall?)

Comment: *> Note that rcx contains a pointer to the PEB and rdx to the entry-point (not the other way around).*

No, that's the wrong claim. I added the screenshots that prove RCX is the *entry-point* and RDX is the *PEB structure*. 
*PEB structure* contains an *image base* at offset 16 (0x10). `RCX = ImageBase+EntryPointRVA`
@PeterCordes please check them out too.

Comment: @TishSerg It's probably because you are inspecting a process created in a suspended state. Before any ntdll code could run. I thought you were inspecting the process at the PE entry-point. My Bad. The answer still stands: there is no reason to believe the kernel would use `rax`, `rbx`. What you are seeing may simply be an artifact of how windows returns from kernel mode (e.g. `sysret` which was not used in 32-bit code).

Comment: In Linux, if you use GDB and `starti` to pause execution before any instructions are executed in user-space, you can see that all registers are zeroed except RSP (and RFLAGS has a consistent non-zero value).  RIP points at the entry point of a static executable, or of the ELF interpreter for dynamic executables.  As you say, this isn't guaranteed by the x86-64 SysV ABI; all other registers can hold garbage (and do in a dynamic executable by the time its _start is reached), except RDX which is either NULL or a pointer that should be registered with atexit.  (For use by the dynamic linker.)